# Using C++ MFC, get list of extensions which are added to browser (Chrome, IE or Firefox)

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, mfc, firefox-addon

Using C++ MFC, how to get a list of the extensions added to browsers? And if possible, how to enable and disable those extensions. 
For example, of extensions installed in Chrome:

[image: click here]

So, can I get those names names and a control that can enable and disable them?

Comment: Sorry. now i have updated my question with screenshot check it.

Comment: There is no standard interface that allows you to query private properties of browser setup. You will have to implement custom solutions for each browser, and I don't know whether those browsers even offer access to this information. Anyway, the question is **way** too broad for Stack Overflow. You need to take the [tour] and read the [help/on-topic] to understand, what questions you shouldn't be asking.

Comment: Are you wanting ways to interface with the browsers to request the info, or alternate ways to find add-ons through inspecting the system?  For all three browsers, it looks like you can get information as to what is installed through a combination of Windows registry and looking for files in the various directories in which they may be installed (non trivial list of locations). Determining what their state is, and enabling/disabling them is possible at least in some cases (may have to parse yet other files).  It would help to know what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Also helpful to know: Are you wanting to find this information only for the current user, or all users? What effective permissions will your program be running with (e.g. specific user, current user, administrator)? For all browser profiles? a specific profile? currently running profile(s)? Default browser? All installed browser versions (e.g Firefox can have extensions explicitly specified for a particular browser install location)?

Comment: I am trying fetch extensions installed and their states(enabled or disabled ), and i want to enable or disable them through my application.

What effective permissions will your program be running with (e.g. specific user, current user, administrator)? - Administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox, you would go to the profile directory, for instance:

"C:\Users\Muhammad Ali Greatest Boxer of All Time\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"

Then you would pick the directory of the profile you interested in. Then you can read all the entreis in `extensions` folder. If you want to get a more accurate view, like if the extensions are enabled/disabled, their titles, you can read inside the profile directory the `addons.json` and `extensions.json` file. I'm not sure of the difference between the two. Please share with us what the differences are after you dig into it.